# What's the difference between "os.dup2"ed file descriptor and "os.open"ed file descriptor when python forks child process?

Tags: python

I have the following two .py files

**The first: close fd0 => open /dev/null as fd0**

```py
import subprocess
import os
import time

os.close(0)
fd_null = os.open("/dev/null", os.O_RDWR)

subprocess.run(["sleep", "12345"]);
time.sleep(1234)
```

This sleep child process `doesn't have` "0 -> /dev/null" in /proc/{PID of child process}/fd.

**The second: open /dev/null as fd_null => close fd0 => dump fd_null to fd0**

```py
import subprocess
import os
import time

fd_null = os.open("/dev/null", os.O_RDWR)
if fd_null != 0:
    os.close(0)
    os.dup2(fd_null, 0)

subprocess.run(["sleep", "12345"]);
time.sleep(1234)
```

This child process `has` "0 -> /dev/null" in /proc/{PID of child process}/fd.

So I just can't understand why these two `fd0`s are different.

Could anyone help me? Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

Oh.I find the answer.

os.dup2 has a parameter "inheritable" which defaults to True. So the "os.dup2"ed file descriptor will be inherited.